# Drawable's size with Coil

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide, android-bitmap, coil

**CONTEXT**

In my app I need to get the full size of my drawables, so I the Glide's library like that :

```kotlin
val bitmap = GlideApp
    .with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(path)
    .submit()
    .get()
```

But I'm on the road to change Glide for Coil, so my request becomes :

```kotlin
val imageLoader = ImageLoader(context)
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
    .data(path)
    .build()
val bitmap = imageLoader.execute(request).drawable?.toBitmap()
```

**ISSUE**

The issue is that with `Coil` I haven't the full size of my bitmap, in contrary to `Glide`.
For exemple with an image in 4000x6000, with `Coil` I get only 1352x2028.

**QUESTION**

How can I get the full size of my bitmap ?

Comment: can you try with ImageRequest, and pass size(Size.ORIGINAL). It will use the original size

Answer (score 0):

**MAYBE SOLUTION**

I have added some parameters in my request and I get the full size :

```kotlin
val imageLoader = ImageLoader(context)
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
    .data(path)
    .size(Int.MAX_VALUE)
    .precision(Precision.INEXACT)
    .build()
val bitmap = imageLoader.execute(request).drawable?.toBitmap()
```